# How can I move files from my host system to Whonix-Workstation?

Tags: whonix

I'm not sure if using the guest additions is safe, but it seems to be the only way to transfer files. I cannot even get copy/paste to work between host and workstation.

Comment: Is this question really about Virtualbox, and not about Whonix? You're going to have to be more specific (or otherwise, it would be reasonable to answer the question with "use scp").

Answer (score 2):

> I'm not sure if using the guest additions is safe,

I am not sure about that either and Whonix's documentation [reflects](https://www.whonix.org/wiki/VirtualBox_Guest_Additions#Warning) that. Whether they are safe or not might be a good question for security.stackexchange.com [while also linking to previous statements about (in)security].

> but it seems to be the only way to transfer files.

Although there is no simple solution, there are [multiple ways](https://www.whonix.org/wiki/File_Transfer) such as ssh.

> I cannot even get copy/paste to work between host and workstation.

Even when guest additions are installed, clipboard sharing is still disabled for security reasons. Whonix documentation [says](https://www.whonix.org/wiki/VirtualBox_Guest_Additions#Warning):

> Clipboard sharing is disabled by default in the Virtual Box VM settings for Whonix-Gateway and Whonix-Workstation. Enable it only temporarily in case you really need it. Go to VirtualBox machine settings -> General -> Advanced -> Shared Clipboard -> Enable -> ok.